# Unable to deploy a node in MAAS 2.1.3 in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: maas, cloud

In previous MAAS versions I successfully deploy a few machines and everything worked fine, but after I updated MAAS to 2.1.3 version using the solution from: https://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/autopilot, I am not able to do deploy anything.

Before trying to deploy the machine I commissioned it from MAAS using an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS amd64 image, after that I tried to deploy it using conjure-up with the Landscape spell, but from the logs I see that it can not even be deployed, so it is not a problem of conjure-up because the same problem happens if a I try to deploy it from MAAS UI.

From the logs you can see this:
Apr 28 15:52:37 Frenzy cloud-init[1205]: Reading package lists...
Apr 28 15:52:37 Frenzy cloud-init[1205]: E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/source/by-hash/SHA256/cd4de9b666f08e418e4ba56c87504e625ab69cb254eaaf2f79c6a6dc3a4cea4e Hash Sum mismatch
Apr 28 15:52:37 Frenzy cloud-init[1205]: E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Apr 28 15:52:37 Frenzy cloud-init[1205]: Cloud-init v. 0.7.9 running 'modules:config' at Fri, 28 Apr 2017 15:52:16 +0000. Up 85.94 seconds.
Apr 28 15:52:37 Frenzy cloud-init[1205]: 2017-04-28 15:52:37,887 - util.py[WARNING]: Running module ntp () failed

Has someone had the same problem? How could be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

That to me looks like nodes in deployment can't reach the repositories. If you are using the MAAS node as a proxy to the internet make sure your IPTABLES is setup to NAT the nodes.